# Can't set image for UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` and I cannot get the image and set for it to show up.

in `viewDidLoad`

```
albumContainer = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 7, 97, 97)];
[self.view addSubview:albumContainer];
```

Method being called from different class

```
NSLog(@"URL:%@",url);
//URL is defined by different class
//URL is http://www.....882546328.jpg (I abbreviated it, but it is a valid url)
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSLog(@"URL LENGTH:%d",[imageData length]);
// URL LENGTH:90158

UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
[albumContainer setImage:tempImage];
```

FULL CODE

PlayerViewController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    playerView = [[AlbumViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AlbumViewController" bundle:nil];
}
-(void)playMusic{

    playerView.url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePathForm];
    playerView.songData = receivedData;
    [loadingSong stopAnimating];
    [playerView play]; 

}
```

AlbumViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    albumContainer = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 7, 97, 97)];
    [self.view addSubview:albumContainer];
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
}

-(void)play{
    NSLog(@"SONGDATA:%d",[songData length]);
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songData error: nil];
    [player stop];

    player.delegate = self;
    player.numberOfLoops = 0;
    player.volume = 0.5; 
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
    NSLog(@"URL:%@",url);
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(@"URL LENGTH:%d",[imageData length]);

    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    [albumContainer setImage:tempImage];

}
```

I checked and albumContainer logged as NULL

Comment: Can you explain what "Method being called from different class" means? if you use `albumContainer`, it means that this method is called within the same class, is it true?

Comment: the code I posted is from the class albumViewController. From a different class playerViewController I am using [album setImage], which is the method posted above.

Comment: What about albumContainer within the second code snippet? How is it defined? try to comment your code or edit it to add addictional info. thank you.

Comment: Can you try hardcoding the UIImage? something like UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithName:@"myImage.png"];  This is just to make sure its not a malformed image problem.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted
I updated my question with the code that I have

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the controller's view has been loaded before you set the image? UIViewControllers don't load their view until it's displayed, and they sometimes unload it when offscreen, so viewDidLoad may not have been called at the point when you call your

```
[albumContainer setImage:tempImage];
```

From outside the controller. Try logging albumContainer to see if it's nil before you set the image, like this:

```
NSLog(@"albumContainer: %@", albumContainer); //might log as null
[albumContainer setImage:tempImage];
```

To force the controller's view to load, you can say:

```
[controller view]; // this will load the view and call viewDidLoad
[albumContainer setImage:tempImage];
```

But you may be better off creating your albumContainer in the initWithNibName:bundle: method of your view controller instead of in the viewDidLoad, like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:bundleOrNil]))
    {
         albumContainer = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 7, 97, 97)];
[self.view addSubview:albumContainer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

That way it will be created at the same time as the controller even if the view hasn't loaded yet.